# React component with props returning strange error (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I get a strange error of " ':' expected."
I'm not sure but maybe I'm doing something bad with props setting for the onChange

This is my component code:

```
import React from "react";

interface TextFieldProps {
    label?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    value?: string;
    onChange?: (e: any) => void;
}

export default function TextField({
    label,
    placeholder,
    value,
    onChange,
}: TextFieldProps) {
    return (
    <>
        <div className="w-full">
            <label htmlFor="textfield" className="flex justify-start w-full text-gray-700 font-medium">
                {label}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-1">
            <input
                type="text"
                name="textfield"
                id="textfield"
                className="shadow-sm focus:ring-[#3182CE] focus:border-[#3182CE] block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => onChange?(e.target.value)}
            />    
        </div>
    </>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't quite now what's causing the error, but the syntax of your `onChange` listener is invalid. It should be `(e) => onChange?.(e.target.value)`;

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `onChange` listener. It should be:

```
(e) => onChange?.(e.target.value)
```

Read more about optional chaining at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax)